# import class and call static method with es6 modules with babel transpiler

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following class definition:

```
class EmberReflux{
  static createActions(actions) {
    console.log(actions);
  }
}

export { EmberReflux };
```

When I import it from a different file:

```
import EmberReflux from '../utils/ember-reflux';

let TodoActions = EmberReflux.createActions(
[
  "addItem",
  "undo",
  "redo"
]);

export { TodoActions };
```

The transpiled looks like this

```
define('ember-reflux/utils/todo-actions', ['exports', 'ember-reflux/utils/ember-reflux'], function (exports, EmberReflux) {

    'use strict';

    var TodoActions = EmberReflux['default'].createActions(["addItem", "undo", "redo"]);

    exports.TodoActions = TodoActions;

});
```

I'm not sure what the default is in `EmberReflux['default']`

I want to call the static class method like this:

```
EmberReflux.createActions
```

But instead I have to call it like this:

```
EmberReflux.EmberReflux.createActions
```

Comment: Try `export default EmberReflux`

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Export `EmberReflux` like you are doing:

   ```
   export { EmberReflux };
   ```

   and then import it like:

   ```
   import { EmberReflux } from '../utils/ember-reflux';
   ```
2. Use `default` when exporting:

   ```
   export default EmberReflux;
   ```

   and import it (like you are doing):

   ```
    import EmberReflux from '../utils/ember-reflux';
   ```

In both cases you can then use your `EmberReflux` like:

```
EmberReflux.createActions();
```

Comment: Why do we need the default in the 2nd example ? In other words why can't we have export EmberReflux directly ?

Comment: Because in the second example you don't destructure `EmberReflux` into its own variable.

Answer (score 11):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, the alexpods's answer is perfect, but for matters of understanding our friend Ced asked:

> Why do we need the default in the 2nd example ? In other words why can't we have export EmberReflux directly ?

When you wrote like this:

```
export { EmberReflux };
```

It's the same writing like this:

```
export { EmberReflux: EmberReflux };
```

That's why you need to run EmberReflux.EmberReflux, the solution is very simple:

```
export default EmberReflux;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class EmberReflux {
    //...
}

module.exports = EmberReflux
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.