# Can't reference static method defined in plugin from an client application

Tags: javascript, plugins, ecmascript-6, static-methods, aurelia

I have js [utilities plugin](https://github.com/Showpitch/utilities/tree/master/src) which contains the following class with a static method, but it can't be referenced from an application that uses this utilities plugin.

```js
export class Helpers {
  static generateGUID() {
    return ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, a=>(a ^ Math.random() * 16 >> a / 4).toString(16));
  }
}
```

client application calling Helpers:

```js
import {Helpers} from 'utilites';
export class MyClass {
  constructor() {
  }

  test() {
    //can't reference Helpers  
    console.log(Helpers.generateGUID());
  }
}
```

But if I change the static method to non-static method like below and reference it from a client app, it can be accessible:

```js
export class Helpers {
  //removed static
  generateGUID() {
    return ([1e7] + -1e3 + -4e3 + -8e3 + -1e11).replace(/[018]/g, a=>(a ^ Math.random() * 16 >> a / 4).toString(16));
  }
}
```

client application calling Helpers:

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {Helpers} from 'sp-utilities';

@inject(Helpers)
export class MyClass {
  constructor(helpers) {
    this.helpers = helpers;
  }

  test() {
    //this works
    console.log(this.helpers.generateGUID());
  }
}
```

I did confirm that if I use the same Helpers code with a static method within an application, I can call it like Helpers.generateGUID() without instantiating Helpers. Does anyone know why this static method in my plugin is not accessible when it's referenced from a client application?

It might be something to do with how I export Helpers class in index.html but I am not sure.

```js
export {Helpers} from './helpers';
export function configure(config) {
  config.globalResources();
}
```

Comment: You should not use classes with static methods at all. Just make it an object with methods. And in this case, you might want to consider exporting the `generateGUID` function directly, as it seems to be the only export.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Babel issue, not Aurelia's. Please check this link for the solution to your issue: [import class and call static method with es6 modules with babel transpiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28974784/import-class-and-call-static-method-with-es6-modules-with-babel-transpiler)

Also, I've checked your plugin code, you don't need the `@noView` there. You need that only for aurelia components, and this are utility classes, so you can safely remove them.

Regards!