# Referencing static method in Class exported from Node JS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

The question is how to refer to other static methods from a static method of a class exported from NodeJS module? Here's a setup. I have following modules: `test1.js`

```
var Parent = class  {
    static smethod1 () {
        return this.smethod2();
    }

    static smethod2 () {
        return "Testing tube";
    }
}

module.exports = {
    Parent:Parent
}
```

Then I have `test2.js` that `require`s this module

```
var mod = require('./test1');
var Parent = mod.Parent;

module.exports = {
    sm1: Parent.smethod1,
    sm2: Parent.smethod2
}
```

Finally, I have a code that is being run in `run.js`

```
var test2 = require('./test2');

console.log(test2.sm1());
```

Naturally, I want to see `"Testing tube"` line printed out. I am getting error

```
        return this.smethod2();
                    ^

TypeError: this.smethod2 is not a function
```

Of course, there's shenanigans on NodeJS where `this` refers to a module, but shouldn't it be referring to a function instead ? Is there way to refer to static method `smethod2` from `smethod1` with current setup ? If not, what are the workarounds ?

Comment: You can have a look on this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/28979516/1681972

Comment: If you have a class with only static methods, this is a sign that you should just exports the functions directly and delete the class, FYI.

Comment: @loganfsmyth This is simplification of course.

Comment: @Ravi, nope. babel-isation didn't seem to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `this` keyword is kind of weird in JavaScript, and doesn't always refer to your instance like in most class based languages. In your case, when you call `test2.sm1()`, `this` is set to the `test2` object, which is

```
{
    sm1: Parent.smethod1,
    sm2: Parent.smethod2
}
```

That object does not have a `smethod2` function.

`this` gets set based on how a function is called in JavaScript, specifically with whatever is before the '`.`': `->test2<-.sm1()`.

There are several workarounds. First, after defining the `Parent` class, you could bind `this` for that function to the class:

```
var Parent = class  {
    static smethod1 () {
        return this.smethod2();
    }

    static smethod2 () {
        return "Testing tube";
    }
}

// bind `this` to `Parent`
Parent.smethod1 = Parent.smethod1.bind(Parent);

module.exports = {
    Parent:Parent
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass `Parent` as an argument to `call` or `apply`, which sets `this` manually for just that one invocation:

```
var Parent = require('./test1');
var test2 = require('./test2');

// call `test2.sm1` with a context of `Parent`    
console.log(test2.sm1().call(Parent));
```

Comment: Take a look at the example from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

Comment: @EvgeniySharapov Interesting, I guess it does make sense in JavaScript that you can call other static methods with `this`. I've changed my answer.

Comment: Looks like using `bind` works ok. I have  `module.exports = {  sm1: Parent.smethod1.bind(Parent),  sm2: Parent.smethod2.bind(Parent) }`
in `test2.js`